# Can I combine these SSH tunneling commands into one command?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a two step solution to access a certain server via SSH:

Step 1, in bash:

```sh
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5000:server2.com:22 server1.com
```

Step 2, in a new bash session:

```sh
ssh -P 5000 127.0.0.1  # This gets me into server2.com
```

Q1: Is there any way I can combine these two commands into one ssh command, and...
Q2:  can I set up one single host entry in my `~/.ssh/config` for this connection (allowing me to just type e.g. `ssh my-tunnel`)?

I suppose this comes down to chaining the hosts in some way. I am new to this and can't quite figure this out...

Comment: you could wrap first command into service to make such tunnel pseudo-permanent. I use this approach to keep such tunnels up 24/7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433031/mount-nfs-share-via-a-hop-server) and was surprised by the fact that ssh supports **jump hosts**.

You can use single command to connect to the target server while ssh will take care about intermediate hop.

```sh
ssh -J server1.com server2.com
```

> -J [user@]host[:port]
>     Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host and then establishing a TCP
>     forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by
>     comma characters.  This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive

And here is the corresponding jump host configuration for SSH config:

```
Host jumphost
    Hostname server1.com
    User $YOUR_USERNAME
    Port 22
Host my-tunnel
    Hostname server2.com
    User $YOUR_USERNAME
    Port 22
    ProxyJump jumphost
```

...enabling the command: `ssh my-tunnel`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I added a code block on the corresponding ssh config.

Comment: `-J` and `ProxyJump` are relatively new (introduced in mid-2016, I believe).