# ssh from A to B to C server to run bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to ssh from **A** server to **B** and to **C** in single command, and then execute bash script in C server, can I do it in single command?

Comment: Check the `-J` option or the `ProxyJump` option in `man ssh_config`.

Comment: is is doable? yes? how? a very simple solution would be `ssh -t B "ssh -t C"`; for other ideas (proxyjump, port forwarding) try a google search on 'ssh through intermediate host` and review the various hits on `stackexchange.com` and its sister sites

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I combine these SSH tunneling commands into one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402158/can-i-combine-these-ssh-tunneling-commands-into-one-command)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the script on the local machine (A), you can do the following:

```
ssh B_server "ssh C_server bash -s " < ./my_script.sh
```

If the script is on the remote server, it's simpler:

```
ssh B_server "ssh C_server /path/to/my/script"
```