# Is there a way to tunnel git commands through an ssh proxy?

Tags: git, github, ssh, proxy, reverse-proxy

I would like to create an ssh client that would send git commands to an ssh proxy that would pipe the data in a bidirectional way from the client to a git server repository (for example hosted on github). Is there an easy way to do this? I tried the following : https://www.systutorials.com/git-through-ssh-tunnel-as-proxy/ with no luck. Hope this is clear.

Something like this with the client sending for example `git clone` and the SSH server funneling back the files to the client machine

SSH Client <---> SSH Server <---> Github Repo

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: Try [`ProxyJump`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61435691/7976758). At the client side configure ssh to use the server as a jump-host for GitHub.

Comment: What isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, for a slightly different use case, namely:

- You can access `github.com` from a host, say, `foo`.
- You actually need to connect to it from a different host, say `bar`.
- You only need to do this interactively - never from cron jobs or some other automated action.
- However, `bar` is not allowed to make any outgoing TCP connections - either directly or via a proxy host.
- You can use SSH to connect from `foo` to `bar`.
- On this connection, you are allowed to set up a reverse SSH tunnel.

In this situation, you can do the following:

1. On `foo`, in `~/.ssh/config`, specify a reverse SSH tunnel for host `bar`.
2. On `bar`, in `~/.ssh/config`, specify the tunnel endpoint as a proxy for host `github.com`.

For example, with reasonably modern versions of OpenSSH, you can use:

```
Host bar
  RemoteForward 22022 bar:22
```

on `foo`, and on `bar`:

```
Host github.com
  ProxyJump localhost:22022
```

Now, if all is well, after doing

```
slogin bar
```

on `foo`, you can use, on `bar`:

```
git clone git@github.com:github/gitignore.git
```

(or whatever repository you wish to use) and this will attempt to use the reverse tunnel from `localhost:22022` to `foo` to connect to `github.com`.

This works for me (with both hosts running Ubuntu 18.04).

Notes:

- It should be possible to replace the `~/.ssh/config` lines on `bar` with something equivalent in `~/.gitconfig`; e.g., using `gitProxy` or `[url (...) .insteadOf (...)]`. I haven't managed to make this work.
- To connect to `github.com` using HTTPS instead of SSH, reverse tunnel to port `443` instead of `22`.
- This is pretty brittle, as it relies on special bits of configuration on `foo` and `bar` working in tandem. So I wouldn't recommend this, except for the given use case, for which it is hard to think of anything better.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which 'systutorials.com' provides is right, being lack of some config info.
The Complete config :

```
vi ~/.ssh/config

Host github.com
        HostName github.com
        User git
        Port 22
        ProxyCommand nc -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

- '127.0.0.1:1080' is your SSH Server, you can modify the address to yours
- good luck

Comment: I got an `nc: invalid option -- 'x'` error when trying to run the command

Comment: 'ProxyCommand nc -proxy 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p'  
or
'ProxyCommand nc -X 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p'
it depends on your nc version, seeking details in 'man nc'. By the way, ensure that the port(1080) is your Socks5 port

Comment: Thanks for the tip arrived at the same conclusion ! Is there a reason you talk about a socks5 proxy when I mentionned an ssh proxy?

Comment: I used the http proxy failed, guessing that the firewall stops it.Socks5 port works for me.Have you succeded in tunneling git commands through the http proxy?

Comment: So basically the intermediate hop in the middle is not an http proxy even though it could be, but is instead an ssh proxy (as seen on https://github.com/dutchcoders/sshproxy) running on port 2222; I can redirect the flow to the proxy but I get an `handshake failed error` for now. Thanks for your help!